# AWS Lambda Authorizer Missing from Method Request: Authorization options

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-jwt-authorizer

This is my first run at the lambda jwt-authorizer so it is probably something quite trivial but...

I have tested the lambda authorizer both in AWS Lambda and in API Gateway Authorisers test rig. Both tests are successful but when I try to secure the api endpoint at the method request only AWS_IAM authorisation is available, anyone any ideas where I have went wrong?

Comment: Did you follow [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/configure-api-gateway-lambda-authorization-with-console.html) to set up the authorizer? Or did you not use the aws console?

Comment: Maybe you can see the lambda authorizer if you refresh the browser?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was a browser refresh, went away, had a game of scrabble and lovely meal with my kids. Came back, I was logged out so the browser refreshed and the authoriser was in the drop down.

Comment: Yup, I experienced the same.  Surprising that it's not quicker.